# Color output strings in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm working on a program that calls python script and shows the output in richtextbox.
I have a problem with coloring specific strings in output.
For example: if the string "hey 123" will appear in the output it will colored red.
Does someone have an answer?
Thanks!
snippet of my code:

```
Process _cmd;
delegate void setTextCallBack(string text);

private void setText (string text)
{
    if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        setTextCallBack d = new setTextCallBack(setText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.richTextBox1.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

```
_cmd = new Process();
_cmd.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;

if (_cmd.Start())
{
    _cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_OutputDataReceived);
    _cmd.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_ErrorDataReceived);
    _cmd.Exited += new EventHandler(_cmd_Exited);

    _cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
    _cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
}
else
{
    _cmd = null;
}
```

```
void _cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cmd.OutputDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_OutputDataReceived);
    _cmd.Exited -= new EventHandler(_cmd_Exited);
}

void _cmd_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateConsole(e.Data, Brushes.Red);
}

void _cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateConsole(e.Data, Brushes.Green);
}

private void UpdateConsole (string text)
{
    UpdateConsole(text, null);
}

private void UpdateConsole(string text, Brush color)
{
    WriteLine(text, color);
}

private void WriteLine(string text, Brush color)
{
    if (text != null)
    {
        setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: please see my updated anwer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Golden Rule** for `RichTextBoxes`: **Don't touch the Text!**

Do not use `richTextBox1.Text += "more text"` to append Text once you have done **any** coloring or formatting! This will mess up **all** formatting you have. There are special functions for everything you need, and you **need** to use those.

To add use

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("more text")
```

Other methods you may need when editing are `Copy, Paste & Cut` plus of course the select properties and methods, you need for the coloring and formatting as well..

To color a piece of text you need to select it and then apply the Color you want like this:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.MistyRose;  // Backcolor
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;            // TextColor
```

Other formatting will use `SelectionFont`, `SelectionIndent`, `SelectionAlignment` and then some..

As you see it all works by first selecting and then working on that selection.

In your code you could change the setText method header to:

```
setText (string text, Color color)
```

and change its code like this:

```
else
{
   int start = richTextBox1.Text.Length;  //*
   richTextBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
   richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;   //*
   richTextBox1.SelectionLength = text.Length;
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
   richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
   richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
   richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

The last three lines are optional; I include them since you seem to want the Caret always at the end..

I would also make it more readable by changing the function's name to something like *addText* or *addColoredText* and maybe even make it more flexible by adding a bool parameter to control whether a `NewLine` should be added or not..

**Update**:

I notice that you are also calling the `UpdateConsole` and `WriteLine` methods with a `null` for the `Brushes`.
This has two problems:

- We don't need a `Brush` but a `Color` for coloring the `RichTextBox`.
- And you can't pass in a `null` for a `Color`.

You could workaround by declaring them to be `SolidBrushes` and the using their `brush.Color`.
But that is just a useless and confusing twist.

Instead pass in the `Color` you want directly and instead of null pass in `Black` or the RTF's `ForeColor` or a default color you define..:

```
UpdateConsole(text, Color.Black);
```

or

```
UpdateConsole(text, richTextBox1.ForeColor);
```

etc..

**Update 2**

Please note the correction (*) in the code; AppendText moves the SelectionStart, so we need to store the start value.

If you have a list of error messages, say

```
List<string> errors;
```

You could fill it from a file, maybe like this:

```
errors = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\errors.txt").ToList();
```

And then either test for equality:

```
setText(text,  errors.Contains(text) ? Color.Red : Color.Blue);
```

Or, if only parts match

```
setText(text,  isError(text) ? Color.Red : Color.Blue);
```

using a function like this:

```
bool isError(string msg)
{ foreach (string err in errors) 
  if (msg.IndexOf(err) >= 0) return true; return false; }
```

Comment: sidenote : It is better to use richTextBox1.AppendText("..") and never richTextBox1.Text += "...." because of possible memory issues. with += you get a new string in memmory each time which can result in memmory issues.

Comment: Well, the old strings will be taken care of by the GC eventually, but having them created in the first place is not the best way. Here the main issue is the Formatting; many folks don't seem to know that problem, judging from several answers to similar questions..

Comment: Thanks. but I have 2 questions. what is the meaning of 'pass the color you want directly', how can i do this actualy?. The second question is how to call a specific string from the output? Thank a lot.

Comment: I have added an example how to pass a Color. I don't understand your 2nd question. Do you mean how to parse the output strings into parts which can then give various colors? Well, i can't tell you, since I don't know the output strings. - However making the recommended change to include a `bool newLine` will be the first step to put text with different colors on the same line..

Comment: my purpose is that the my pyhon script can print error strings. I know these string (for example: "device could not configure"). If this string will appear, I want that it will colored red, and only this string, not all the output. did you understand? You can have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I guess you will need to either have a list of those error messages and then check the list for a hit, or, much better, grab an status/error code. But: Are not all messages on errOut error messages?

Comment: Not all my error messages on errOut error messages. what do you mean by saying grab an status/error code. I'm sorry for all these questions, i'm quite new with c#.

Comment: I guess you can't get at any status info other than those messges. So you will need to identify those that are realy error messages. The good news is that you can expect those to not change; otoh you may well find that you forgot a few, so extesibilty is one aim.

Comment: Also you should decide/find out if the messages will actually be known verbatim or whether they may have variations like "device xyz not found" with xyz being a variable string.. In the first case you can put the messages in a `List<string>` and check with `Contains`.

Comment: In the 2nd case you will take a sufficiently unique part of each message and try to find it in each outputline using `IndexOf`..

Comment: Do you have a list of your Python's messages? [Here](http://www.wingware.com/psupport/python-manual/2.6/library/errno.html?highlight=error%20messages) is one I found on the web.  They seem to be usable verbatim.. I have added code to do the error checking...