# Moving numbers in richTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, numbers, richtextbox, move, tetris

I need to solve behavior of four numbers, which will move down or rotate as the meaning of the game Tetris. This is that I want to do on richTextBox in C#, but my code is still not working good. I want to do as illustrated below. How can I do to that numbers are moving in right direction?

0 0 0 0 **1** **1** **1** **1** 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

after moving down four numbers of "1"

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 **1 1 1 1** 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

or also after rotating clockwise four numbers of "1"

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Here is my code.

```
string[] pole8x8 = new string[400];
string[] pole4x4 = new string[4*2];
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
int len = 52;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < pole8x8.Length; i+=2)
    {
        pole8x8[i] = "0 ";
        richTextBox1.Text += pole8x8[i];
        richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pole4x4.Length; i+=2)
    {
        pole4x4[i] = "1 ";
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 18;
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = pole4x4[i];
        numbers.Add(pole4x4[i]);
     }

 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     richTextBox1.SelectionStart += len;

     foreach (string s in numbers)
     {
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = s;
     }

 }
```

Comment: please rename your buttons/etc to give them more meaningful names - it's a complete pet-hate of mine!

Comment: It's unclear what, exactly, you want help with.  Causing your "pieces" to move down the text box?  Also, your variables look to be a bit misnamed.  You have "pole4x4" and "pole8x8"  I think that pole4x4 is supposed to be your "line" piece and pole8x8 is supposed to be a row in your well.  But it's unclear.  (4x4 defines a square containing 16 points... 4 across and 4 down, not a "pole".  Similarly, 8x8 would be a square with 64 points.  If I read this correctly, you mean them to be 1x4 and 1x8.  Is that correct?)

Comment: I'm sorry for unreasonable names of variables. pole4x4 is related to four numbers consisting of "1" and pole8x8 is for others numbers like "0", which is string in array by a size 400. You can it try in C# and easy it figure out.

Comment: Besides changing the characters to show the board like you want it, there is another probelm with your code. (At least!) Do you have a spcial reason to use a `RichTextBox`??? It is a rather weird choice, over, say a `DataGridView`.. Please hae a look at the [rules I set up in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957207/color-output-strings-in-richtextbox/25957583#25957583), or else your coloring will never work right..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that your implementation needs some refinement, but here is some code that will start with a couple of shapes and move them down the well.  They... 'crumble' at the bottom, unlike tetris where the shapes retain their rigidness.  But I think this answers your question.  the rest is up to you.

Edit:  I forgot to mention.  My RichTextBox is set to use Courier New font.  (and non-true type font should work.)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _tickCounter = 0;
    private int _tickLimit = 500;  // set to 10 or something for the game
    private string[,] _dataArray;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _tickCounter++;
        if (_tickCounter >= _tickLimit)
        {
            // add a piece
            AddNewPieceToWell(true);
            _tickCounter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Move the current pieces downward.
            for (int rowCounter = _dataArray.GetUpperBound(0); rowCounter >= 1; rowCounter--)
            {
                for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter <= _dataArray.GetUpperBound(1); colCounter++)
                {
                    if (_dataArray[rowCounter, colCounter] == " " && _dataArray[rowCounter - 1, colCounter] == "0")
                    {
                        _dataArray[rowCounter, colCounter] = "0";
                        _dataArray[rowCounter - 1, colCounter] = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DrawWell();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeWell();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void InitializeWell()
    {
        _dataArray = new string[,]{
            {" ", " ", "0", "0", "0", "0", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {"0", "0", "0", "0", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "},
            {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}
        };
        DrawWell();
    }

    private void DrawWell()
    {
        rtbWell.Text = string.Empty;
        for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter <= _dataArray.GetUpperBound(0); rowCounter++)
        {
            for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter <= _dataArray.GetUpperBound(1); colCounter++)
            {
                rtbWell.Text += _dataArray[rowCounter, colCounter];
            }
            rtbWell.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    private void AddNewPieceToWell(bool RandomPiece = true)
    {
        // ToDo
    }
}
```